# Building a bar graph with absolutely positioned li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a "bar graph" with `<li>` elements:

In order for the `<li>`s to display as vertical "bars", and from the bottom up, I positioned them as `absolute` and with `bottom: 0px`. Now, I have it working manually like so:

```
#graph {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    position: relative;
}
#graph ul li {
    background: #0071bc;
    height: 200px;     /* the height will eventually be dynamic */
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#graph ul li:nth-child(1) { left: 10px; }
#graph ul li:nth-child(2) { left: 130px; }
#graph ul li:nth-child(3) { left: 250px; }    /* and so on and so forth */
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRrRj/)

The `<li>` elements are seperated like this by 20px - one can do the math here. The problem arises when I want to add an extra `<li>` to the list. It turs out like so: [another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRrRj/1/)

See the problem?

Now, I can add more CSS to accommodate for the extra `<li>` but to have to do this every time would become tedious and inefficient.

Any solutions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QSz7T/

Comment: You could let sass do all the maths for you: http://sass-lang.com

Comment: @supernova, yes, I've tried that, the `<li>`s don't sit at the border at the bottom of the `#graph`

Comment: @LarsEbert, nice one! I hadn't thought of that, will give it a go

Comment: Are these li's going to be added dynamically (i.e. you don't know how many there will be)? If using a preprocessor like sass or less doesn't work, doing this with jQuery/JS would be super simple. (But no JS would be nicer :P )

Comment: @robooneus, yes the `<li>`s will be added dynamically with php. I've tried using a for loop in JS but I can't seem to grab the `<li>`s individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to handle things on the fly, you can use a function to iterate through the lis and set the `left` position.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHChR/1/)

```
$('li').each(function(index){
        var xPos = index * 110 + 10;
        $(this).css('left', xPos);
});
```

If there is any in-page interaction (like dynamically adding after page-load), you could do something similar and just change the `$(li).each()` to whatever you need.

---

If you know they will never exceed a certain number, just adding the CSS for it might be better, though. (Iterating through li:nth-child(n) {} for the max number of lis possible).

Comment: Glad to help. Check the edit I just made, too... accidentally had a superfluous line left in the code.